# Convert Multi-layered GML file to GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr, gml, anaconda

I have the GreenSpace GML file from https://osdatahub.os.uk/

When using ogr2ogr with this command:  `-f GeoJSON -lco RFC7946=YES OSOpenGreenspace.geojson OSOpenGreenspace.gml`

I am given this Error by the console: ERROR 1: Layer 'GreenspaceSite' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver

Does this imply that my GML has multiple layers and as such given GeoJSON can't handle multiple layers I will have to convert them individually?

If so how do I figure out all the layers in the GML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoJSON can have only one layer https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html#layer

> A GeoJSON datasource is translated to single OGRLayer object with
> pre-defined name OGRGeoJSON

The layer name part is not true any more but that is documented later.

The new JSON-FG driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/jsonfg.html supports multiple layers through the featureType mechanism https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/jsonfg.html#dataset-creation-options. JSON-FG is an OGC standard draft. Because it is a draft it is not very usable format yet. Meanwhile you must convert each layer into separate GeoJSON files.

The list of layers in the GML file can be fetched with ogrinfo.

```
ogrinfo my.gml
```

Comment: Thank you @user30184, I think you answered my previous question too...! 

For the noobs out there like me who have begun their GIS journey, to convert a specific layer like above, here is the command: ```ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON output.geojson input.gml layername ```